# Why does an apostrophe stop stringstream/printing?

Tags: c++, stringstream

The funciton split takes a wstring and a wstring array as arguments and should save the words of the wstring in the array.

```
int split(std::wstring line, std::wstring a[]) {
    std::wstringstream wordStream;
    wordStream << line;
    std::wstring word;

    int wordCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; wordStream >> word; i++) {
        a[i] = word;
        wordCount++;
    }

    return wordCount;

}
```

It worked fine, but then I tried it with this sentence:

```
int main() {
    std::wstring a[100];
    std::wcout << split(L"Confounding declarations of ISIS’ decline, twin offensives in Ramadi and Palmyra have become a sudden showcase for the terrorist group’s disciplined adherence to its core philosophies.", a) << std::endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        std::wcout << a[i] << "|";
    }
}
```

And I got this:

```
26
Confounding|declarations|of|ISIS
```

It stops at the apostrophe: ’

I tried replacing it with ' and it worked again. What is happening here?

Comment: works fine [here](https://ideone.com/a6wT8K)

Comment: And what environment (OS and compiler version) are you running this in? For the provided code in Ubuntu it works for me as expected. Also, check that you indeed save with a correct encoding.

Comment: I'm running it in Xcode on OS X 10.10 with with Apple LLVM. The apostrophe doesn't only stop the printing, but also it just stops executing the code after that. But I don't get an error.

Comment: What is the value of that character? (in hex encoded binary)

Comment: Did you save the file in UTF/Unicode format?

Comment: There is something very strange going on. If I write your results to a file, it contains only one byte — "C". (Also on OSX 10.10.) I have no idea what the problem might be.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks for trying it. I don't know what it is. I've had other problems with this compiler, I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: I don't know much about the compiler and the platform. But I can suggest one thing: Try writing your own function that accepts wide-character (pointer), and loop it. See if you get the correct value (or do you get a null char?)